# Visually change URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I'm trying to visually change
www.example.com/?lang=en
to
www.example.com/en

but it doesn't work...

Here is my code :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?lang=(\w+)$ /$1 [L]
```

I don't want any redirection, I just want to see the result on the URL.

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: `^(.*)\?lang=(\w+)$` is never going to match - RewriteRule only checks the _path_ conponent of the URL against the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://yoursite.com/en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://yoursite.com/de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://yoursite.com/nl/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://yoursite.com/fr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://yoursite.com/es/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|de|nl|fr|es)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain I agree with using `HTTP:Accept-Language` but this'll do the trick - would be nice if you'd added a brief explanation as to *why* this works though, for the OP and any future visitors ;)